# Firebase create user error is caught after then block is executed

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vue-router

I have a signup page in my `Vue` app. In this page I accept the users input and after validating it I add the user to the `firebase auth`. If this is successful I want the page to navigate to the login page. Her is my signup page:

```
<template>
  <div class="signup container">
      <form @submit.prevent="signup" class="card-panel">
          <h2 class="center teal-text">Signup</h2>

          <div class="field">
              <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
              <input type="text" name="firstName" v-model="firstName">
          </div>
          <p class="red-text center" v-if="firstNameFeedback"> {{firstNameFeedback}} </p>

          <div class="field">
              <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
              <input type="text" name="lastName" v-model="lastName">
          </div>
          <p class="red-text center" v-if="lastNameFeedback"> {{lastNameFeedback}} </p>

          <div class="field">
              <label for="phone">Phone number:</label>
              <input type="tel" name="phone" v-model="phone">
          </div>
          <p class="red-text center" v-if="phoneFeedback"> {{phoneFeedback}} </p>

          <div class="field">
              <label for="email">Email:</label>
              <input type="email" name="email" v-model="email">
          </div>
          <p class="red-text center" v-if="emailFeedback"> {{emailFeedback}} </p>

          <div class="field">
              <label for="password">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" name="password" v-model="password">
          </div>
          <div class="field">
              <label for="repassword">Retype Password:</label>
              <input type="password" name="repassword" v-model="rePassword">
          </div>

          <p class="red-text center" v-if="rePasswordFeedback"> {{rePasswordFeedback}} </p>
          <div class="field center">
              <button class="btn deep-teal">Signup</button>
          </div>
      </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import db from '@/firebase/init'
import firebase from 'firebase'

export default {
    name: 'Signup',
    data(){
        return{
            firstName: null,
            firstNameFeedback: null,
            lastName: null,
            lastNameFeedback: null,
            phone: null,
            phoneFeedback: null,
            email: null,
            password: null,
            rePassword: null,
            emailFeedback: null,
            passwordFeedback: null,
            rePasswordFeedback: null
        }
    },
    methods:{
        signup(){
            if (this.firstName == null) {
                this.firstNameFeedback = "First name is required"
            }
            if (this.lastName == null) {
                this.lastNameFeedback = "Last name is required"
            }
            if (this.phone == null) {
                this.phoneFeedback = "Phone number is required"
            }
            if (this.email == null) {
                this.emailFeedback = "Email is required"
            }
            if (this.password == null) {
                this.passwordFeedback = "Password is required"
            }
            if (this.password != this.rePassword) {
                this.rePasswordFeedback = "Passwords do not match"
            }
            if (this.firstName && this.lastName && this.email && this.phone && this.password && this.rePassword && this.password == this.rePassword) {
                this.firstNameFeedback = null
                this.lastNameFeedback = null
                this.emailFeedback = null
                this.phoneFeedback = null
                this.passwordFeedback = null
                this.rePasswordFeedback = null

                firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).then(
                    cred => {
                        db.collection('admin').doc(cred.user.uid).set({
                            admin: this.$route.params.admin,
                            email: this.email,
                            fname: this.firstName,
                            phone: this.phone,
                            surname: this.lastName,
                            'user.uid': cred.user.uid
                        })
                    }
                ).catch(
                    err => {
                        console.log(err.message)
                        this.rePasswordFeedback = err.message
                    }
                ).then(
                    this.$router.push({name: 'Login'})
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
    .signup{
        max-width: 600px;
        margin-top: 60px;
    }
    .signup h2{
        font-size: 2.4em;
    }
    .signup .field{
        margin-bottom: 16px;
    }
</style>
```

As you see in the code I am catching the error of the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method in the catch block. But the page first routes to the login page and executes the catch. I know this because the error message is logged to the console after the app goes to the login page. Ay help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If your code triggers the `catch()` block it means that there was an error with the call to the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` or to the `set()` methods. What is the output of `console.log(err.message)`?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec it says there is a user with this email address. Yes I know there is an error but I don't want the then method t execute if there is an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the promise returned by the asynchronous `set()` method to correctly [chain the promises](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining), and also adapt the last [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) block which does not contain any callback function.

So the following should do the trick:

```
    firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
      .then((cred) => {
        return db.collection('admin').doc(cred.user.uid).set({
          admin: this.$route.params.admin,
          email: this.email,
          fname: this.firstName,
          phone: this.phone,
          surname: this.lastName,
          'user.uid': cred.user.uid,
        });
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.$router.push({ name: 'Login' });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
        this.rePasswordFeedback = err.message;
      });
```

---

Note that you may not need to reroute to the login page, since the call to the [`createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#create-user-with-email-and-password) actually logs in the user when successful, as mentioned in the doc ("On successful creation of the user account, this user will also be signed in to your application"). So you could directly reroute it to a "secured" page.